# find out the String is url

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

Is there a way to find out user entered text is webiste url .

For example if user entered

```
www.yahoo.com

www.google.fr
```

can we detect it is a url String ?

thanks

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5617749/593709) and this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2230676/593709)

Comment: why you do not use regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.net.URL` to detect presence of url in string.

see the following thread :

[How to detect the presence of URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285619/how-to-detect-the-presence-of-url-in-a-string)

Answer (score 13):

```
try { URL url = new URL("url_string"); }
catch (MalformedURLException e) { /* invalid URL */ }
```