# How can I validate a URL in android

Tags: android, regex

How can I validate URL in android... I am trying to use regex but it is always returning false even if the url is correct

Code used:

```
private boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        return URL.matcher(email).matches();
}
    public final Pattern URL = Pattern.compile(
              "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:ww‌​w.|[-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/.\\w-_]*)?\\??(?:[-\\+=&;%@.\\w_]*)#?‌​(?:[\\w]*))?)/"
      );
```

I have got very basic knowledge in regex, so I don't know whether the above used string is correct. Please help...

Comment: url is different from an email address

Comment: the pattern is of URL, forgot to change the Pattern's name

Comment: Check this answer which provides a few validation tools:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5930532/1374065

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating URL in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)
One more thing how can I validate without `http://` or `https://` ie the websites starting with `www` should be considered valid

Answer (score 23):

As your question is more specific to android. You can use this

```
android.util.Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to find a URL inside a text comprised of string other than just the URL, use this

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(bodyText).find()
```

matches() tries to match the string length to exactly that of the URl, while find() will look for the string in the entire text