# Checking Uri if they starts with "http://" or "https://"

Tags: android, uri, startswith

i am checking if a string starts with "http://" or "https://". I want to add "http://" at the beginning with they aren't. However,

```
String str = "www.stackoverflow.com"
str = "http://" + str;
```

would result in

```
str = "http//stackoverflow.com"
```

The ":" in the middle is missing. What should I do?

Comment: I can't understand how `:` is missing ? It should not.

Comment: are trying to strip www and add http(s) ?

Answer (score 2):

I used "android.webkit.URLUtil" class for checking Url. But it has its own limitation.

I detected that it allow spaces in urls.

```
// if url contains http://

 if(url.contains("http://")){
    // Validate URL
    if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Invalid URL specified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;

         }else{ 

         // Your URL is Ready   

        }                       
         }else{// if url does not contains http://

        url = "http://" + url;  //add it to yur url 

         // Validate URL
        if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) { 
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Invalid URL specified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
            }else{ 
                    // Your link is ready   

                    }               
        }
```

[URLUtil at Android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html)

[Stack Over flow Answer how to validate a URL / website name in EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617749/how-to-validate-a-url-website-name-in-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(requestUrl)) {
           // it means url start with http or https
        }else{
      // do relevant action
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "www.stackoverflow.com"
str = "http://" + str;
```

The above one is resulting as expected only i.e., "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
Can you post your exact code what are you doing there.