# Check String is URL in android code?

Tags: java, android, url

I allow user to input text string in my EditView. When I get Editview text, I want to validate if it is URL link or not? Can any one give Android code function? Thanks

Comment: Another is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617749/how-to-validate-a-url-website-name-in-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 6):

Use WEB_URL pattern in Patterns (android.util.Patterns) Class

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(inputTextForURLEdittext.toLowerCase()).matches();
```

It will return true if URL is valid and false if URL is invalid.
For more info refer to this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using [URLUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29) .

```
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(urlString)) {
    // URL is valid
}
```

Hope it will be work for you.

Comment: it gives strings like "http://" as valid URL which isn't true