# Android web browser

Tags: android, android-studio, web, browser

please predecessors, Am creating a web browser homepage in android studio and want to be able to input URL from the same editText as that of my search.
have been able to take search and load google results, but URL still end up in searched instade of loading the URL website.

this is my codes.

```
    EditText searchEditText = rootView.findViewById (R.id.searchEditText);
    ImageButton searchBt = rootView.findViewById (R.id.searchBt);

    searchBt.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String searchQuery = searchBar.getText ().toString ();
            if(URLUtil.isValidUrl (searchQuery)){
                webView.loadUrl (searchQuery);
            }else {
                String searchURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchQuery;
                webView.loadUrl (searchURL);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617749/how-to-validate-a-url-website-name-in-edittext-in-android/7754297) question. I think Pattern matcher is more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because your URL doesn't have `https` at the beginning.
Try using some other mechanism to determine if the URL is valid.

For example, use **WEB_URL** pattern in Patterns Class

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(potentialUrl).matches()
```