# Make UIAutomation click on partcular text in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, ui-automation

I have dialog box, which has a message written in it. In that message there is a hyperlink using CDATA. Now when the automation is run, it clicks on the center of the dialog box. And hence whether the hyperlink works or not cannot be determined.

My question here is how do I make the automation test script click on the hyperlink to check if it's working.

Comment: can you tell me for the automation which tool you are using for it .. .?

Comment: We are using HAT as the uiautomation tool.

Comment: but i think the preferable way for this is that...

Comment: Sorry I can't ee your full comment

Comment: sorry for that.
but i think the preferable way for this is that...
1.) when your automation tool is clicking on the center of the on the dialog box before it,
you should check the malform Url 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905075/how-to-check-if-url-is-valid-in-android

Is valid then ok you should continue otherwise write your logic.

Comment: Yes that would be the go-to answer, i thought of that. But the click on the center doesnot trigger anything, and the uiautomation tool cannot contain the logic for checking if the URL is valid.

Plus the URL is hyperlinked in the form of CDATA and taken from strings.xml. Is there a way when the tool clicks on the center, I can extract text and check for url validity. The above link goes in the source code, which has nothing to do with Uiautomation script