# Picasso doesn't tolerate empty String URL?

Tags: android, picasso

I have a viewHolder that loads up an image using Picasso. The DB will return a path of URL as String. So I have my code as below (Using Kotlin)

```
  Picasso.with(context).load(url).error(placeholder).transform(transformation)
            .placeholder(placeholder).into(this)
```

It loads fine. However, sometimes the URL is empty. I'm expecting it to load the placeholder instead. But it crash out as below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
```

This would force me to explicitly do a check, which is not ideal

```
if (url == null || url.isEmpty()) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(placeholder).transform(transformation).into(this)
} else {
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).error(placeholder).transform(transformation)
            .placeholder(placeholder).into(this)
}
```

Is this expected that Picasso will crash when a URL String is empty instead of loading the placeholder?

Comment: Yes, it would be a lot of overhead (relatively)  to load Picasso for an empty string.

Comment: Wouldn't picasso handle internally where if a string is empty, or the url is inaccessible, it should fallback to the "error" or "placeholder" image?

Comment: It could, but sometimes it is just easier for libraries to assume you are going to be using the appropriate values than it is to do checks everywhere sometimessometimes. Puts some responsibility on the user.

Comment: @zgc7009, when you say 'it could', perhaps you could share with me how... I would like to have that in, to eliminate the extra checks on my end. So I don't need to worry how the DB pass in value. If they are valid I'll post the image, else I'll fall back to the error image. Thanks.

Comment: No I'm saying they could design it so it does, but it isn't designed that way. You have to pass it a string. Unfortunately with programming sometimes checks are just a part of it

Comment: Thanks. Facts of life. I could perhaps add Try-Catch to handle it on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc for Picasso.load()](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/) explicitly states that it will throw an IllegalArgumentException when the URL is null or empty.  So that's what you can expect.

Comment: Thanks. Facts of life. I could perhaps add Try-Catch to handle it on my end.

Comment: It's going to be more efficient and readable if you simply check for empty or null yourself and take appropriate action.  It's a very common thing to do in java.

Comment: Cool. Like what I did above. Just thought in case there's some other error condition I might miss... since I don't have control of the DB entirely, it could be other things that could cause Picasso to throw exception. p/s: On my program, if the input is invalid, then I'll ignore it and show the placeholder image. ... By the way, I like your Kotlin blog. Cool post!

Comment: Thanks!  Glad you got something out of it.  :-)

Comment: A String consisting entirely of white spaces like `"   "` will also cause the exception.

Comment: In fact, Passing null as a path will not trigger any request but will set a placeholder, if one is specified. Only throw IllegalArgumentException if path is empty or blank string.

Answer (score 6):

This might be too late but i encountered this error today and after read the documentation of [Picasso#load](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java#L327) method it states that passing empty or blank string will cause the method to throw `IllegalArgumentException` and passing a null will not throw an exception but trigger [RequestCreator#error](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java#L143) which will load error image if one is provided otherwise the target will display nothing.

if you have no control over the image url (say its coming from server) you can try the following:

```
 mPicasso.load(photo.isEmpty() ? null : photo)
                .placeholder(placeholder)
                .error(error_placeholder)
                .into(target);
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope it helps you:

```
if (item.getImagen().isEmpty()) { //url.isEmpty()
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }else{
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getImagen())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(holder.imageView); //this is your ImageView
    }
```

Comment: Try not to post answers that consist solely of code. A few lines of explanation make answers like this much easier to understand at a glance and much more liable to be upvoted/accepted.

Comment: Its safer to use TextUtils.IsEmpty (str) then str.IsEmpty() as it checks for null rather than throwing an exception if str is null

Comment: `.equals("")` worked in my case, but, anyway, this solution is gold.

Answer (score 2):

It it late but I ran into the same problem and I solved by just passing a Uri instead of the url. just pass your url like `Uri.parse(url)`.
It will be something like this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(url).error(placeholder).transform(transformation)
            .placeholder(placeholder).into(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the string before loading into Picasso.

```
public static boolean isBlank(String string) {
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(string.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Warning: Its not enough to check the emptiness of the url String

You should trim the url String first and then do the empty check. Otherwise a String like `" "` can break your app.

This is how I use it.

```
if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.trim().isEmpty())
{
    imageUrl = null;
}

Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(imageUrl) // its safe to pass null, but not "" or " "
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .into(mImageView);
```

Check the source code of Picasso to learn why.

Discussions on the topic: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/609

Answer (score 0):

You can check if url is empty by using below method

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(url.trim()) && url.trim().length >0){
    if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()){

    }
}
```

Source Url validation : [How to check if URL is valid in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905075/how-to-check-if-url-is-valid-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

yes,  picasso expects  non null and non empty  values so what i suggest is to use the helper TextUtils to handle this.
Here an example.

```
String imagenUser = listaComentarios.get(position).getAvatar();
 
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imagenUser)) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Avatar imagenes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  holder.imagen_usuario.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
} else {
  Picasso.get()
    .load(imagenUser)
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .into(holder.imagen_usuario);
}
```