# How to check if the URL is valid in android?

Tags: android, url

How to check if the URL is valid  or not.
`Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlString).matches() returns false` for android version 5 and below.
Also ,various links say `URLUtil.isValidUrl(urlString)` is not good to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if URL is valid in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905075/how-to-check-if-url-is-valid-in-android)

Answer (score 8):

Shouldn't use URLUtil to validate the URL as below.

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

**because it gives strings like "http://" as valid URL which isn't true**

Better way is

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(potentialUrl).matches()
```

It will return True if URL is valid and false if URL is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Your Solution is:

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url);
```

or You can use if above code doesnt work.

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
```

Comment: the below code didn't care about "http://" so I used the top one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Url is valid or not using two methods

1. `URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)`

   Problem is : it return true for *"http://"*  which is wrong
2. Second way is

   `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(potentialUrl).matches();`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use combination of both:)

```
fun isUrlValid(url: String?): Boolean {
        url ?: return false
        return Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches() && URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
    }
```