# email match boolean logic android

Tags: java, android, boolean

I know there's already a tool to check web address in Java. But I don't know why this logic does not work. The alert message does not go away even if the input is right. Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(checkInput()){
        String email = getResources().getString(R.string.email);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    }else{
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
        alert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.valid_input));
        alert.show();
    }

}

public boolean checkInput(){

        return (uri.startsWith("http:")&&!uri.equals(""));
}
```

Comment: related [How to check if URL is valid in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4905075/7666442)

Comment: Use Regex instead, [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project i use like this :

```
    if (CheckInternetConection.isInternetConnection(SplashScreenActivity.this)) {
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                                    String to[] = {"bugfreeRam@gmail.com"};
                                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
                                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
                                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Database File");
                                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
 } else {

                                    new SweetAlertDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this)
                                            .setTitleText("Alert!")
                                            .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_connection))
                                            .show();
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your check to from

```
(uri.startsWith("http:")&&!uri.equals(""))
```

to this

```
(uri.startsWith("http"))
```

Firstly, `url` can start with either `http` or `https`, so your check above does not cover the second case.
Secondly, if `startsWith` already passed, there is no need to check `!uri.equals("")`